# Mead turn moldy?

Tags: mead

First mead attempt. Think it went moldy but looking for other opinions. Made it four weeks ago. Racked last week. Thinking about second racking. About 1/4" yeast sediment so far and little to no activity through the airlock. What do you meadeers think?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like yeast rafts. You will be fine. How does it taste.

Comment: Racked today. Tastes bitty and dry. Going to let it sit a bit longer and see what it does. Currently at 1.001, starting was 1.305. Was small batch ~4g in 5g carboy. I have 3.5 give or take left. Started with 15lbs of raspberry honey and used a champaign yeast.

Comment: Sure that's not 1.135? For it to be 1.305 in 4 gallons, you'd need ~34 lbs of honey. (Also, if it went from 1.305 to 1.001, it'd be ~34% ABV)

Answer (score 0):

Looks fuzzy to me, but may just be refraction of the fermentor. If it is fuzzy then it's some sort of fungus or bacteria. Most of these are aerobic (needing oxygen) common if the secondary is too late to fill the head space with co2.

It "may" not be harmful. Usually the blue and black molds are cause for alarm.

I would rack to an other vessel purged of oxygen, giving care to not disturb what's on top leave behind a good inch of the surface mead. If it repeats in the new vessel it may be too contaminated. While it's unlikely any harmful pathogens are in the mead it may not taste that great.